# Salesforce SOQL alternative for WHERE IN SELF

Tags: soql

### SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT parentid FROM table1 WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL)
```

### SOQL(NOT POSSIBLE):

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT parentid FROM Account WHERE parentid != null)
```

Does anyone knows alternative?

Comment: You want to get the list of accounts that has parent account,Am I right?

Comment: Instead of soql, Describe what you want to achieve in the above sql ?

Comment: This answer has same query which you need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error when you run the query:

> ```
> WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE parentid != null)
> ```
>
> The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type

Also mentioned in [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm):

> SOQL doesn’t support all advanced features of the SQL SELECT command. For example, you can’t use SOQL to perform arbitrary join operations, use wildcards in field lists, or use calculation expressions.

If you're using apex, you would need to split queries into 2. One for collecting the record Id's for second query's filter.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your SOQL query, you want to select names of all accounts, that are not parents for any account.

I tried to achieve it with parent-child query, but `Account` has only `Assets`, `Cases`, and `Contacts` children.

So I tried such a workaround, querying

```
select AccountId, Account.Name
from Contact
where AccountId != null
    and AccountId not in (
        select ParentId
        from Account
        where ParentId != null
        )
group by AccountId, Account.Name
```

This is not a 100% perfect solution. in order to query valid results make sure that each `Account` has at least one related `Contact`.

To get 100% correct results you need to use Apex.

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
for(List<Account> withParentsAccounts :[
    select Id, ParentId
    from Account
    where parentId != null
    ]){
    for(Account withParentAccount :withParentsAccounts){
         parentIds.add(withParentAccount.ParentId); 
    }
}
List<Account> nonParentAccounts = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Id not in :parentIds
    ];
```